# Do i need to release/autorelease my stuff for iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Hear a rumor that the new version of xcode is going to add the release statements for you.

So if I init something do I actually have to release it?

Comment: Don't code based on rumors. If the tools you use now don't do it for you, then you need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're referring to is called [Automatic Reference Counting](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/). ARC is a feature in recent versions of the LLVM compiler that will be included in a future version of Xcode. You have to specifically enable ARC to get the benefits from it, and it includes its own set of rules that you need to follow. Right now, unless you're compiling with a prerelease toolset, you need to do your own retains and releases. And even when the feature is released, you will need to specifically code for it — Xcode won't just helpfully correct your mistakes.